# Permissions sets not be converted through sfdx

Tags: salesforcedx

I pulled down my mdapipkg and ran covert and it isn't converting it. Not getting an error.  Any idea on why that might be, a month ago it was working, not changed locally in my sfdx environment since then.

Comment: Could be a bug !

Comment: okay, what do I do about that bug?

Comment: Any errors you get you want to list .Also produce a small git repo where one can reproduce it .

Comment: There are no errors, everything but workflows and permissions convert just fine.

Comment: My guess - the tracking data for your scratch org (held locally under the .sdfx folder) is "corrupt". Find the folder under .sfdx that corresponds to the user for your scratch org and delete it. Then try the steps again. (If pulling complains of conflict, do a force - this will overwrite what you have locally so backup if you need.)